# In Elm, how can I listen to mousewheel events generated on a node

Tags: elm

See the following example [on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/6XXz8Kmj6a1/1):

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)
import Html.Events exposing (Options, onClick, onWithOptions)
import Json.Decode as JD
import Json.Decode.Extra exposing ((|:))
import Result exposing (withDefault)
import String as S


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , view = view
        }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( Model "", Cmd.none )


type alias Model =
    { message : String
    }


type Msg
    = Zoom MouseWheelEvent
    | Clicked


type alias MouseWheelEvent =
    { deltaX : Float
    , deltaY : Float
    , clientX : Float
    , clientY : Float
    }



update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Zoom e ->
            ( { model | message = toString e }, Cmd.none )
        Clicked ->
            ( { model | message = "Clicked!" }, Cmd.none )


decodeMouseEvent : JD.Decoder Msg
decodeMouseEvent =
    JD.map Zoom
        (JD.succeed MouseWheelEvent
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
        )


mouseAttribute : String -> JD.Decoder Float
mouseAttribute k =
    JD.at [ k ] JD.string |> JD.andThen readFloat


readFloat : String -> JD.Decoder Float
readFloat n =
    JD.succeed (withDefault 0 (S.toFloat n))


view : Model -> Html Msg
view m =
    div []
        [ p [] [ text <| "message: " ++ m.message ]
        , div
            [ onWithOptions "mousewheel" (Options True True) decodeMouseEvent
            , onClick Clicked
            , style
                [ ( "height", "250px" )
                , ( "width", "250px" )
                , ( "background-color", "green" )
                ]
            ]
            [ p [] [ text "Zoom here" ]
            ]
        ]


subscriptions m =
    Sub.none
```

I want to capture the mousewheel event on a specific element. This is to do with creating a zoom effect on an SVG image.

As per the example, if I attach a listener to a specific element then the `update` function does not get called. The event appears to be captured by the document body and does not reach my target element. So how do I go about getting my event handler to trigger?

I appreciate it might be possible to do this with ports, but it seems wrong to grab something which is occurring at the `document.body` level, when I am only interested in capturing it when it occurs over a specific element.

Is it the case that `mousewheel` is only ever viewed as a document level event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event *is* being triggered but your decoder is failing because the fields `event.deltaX`, `event.deltaY`, etc are not strings but floats. AFAIK Elm silently ignores the event if the decoder fails. It works if I change the decoder from:

```
decodeMouseEvent : JD.Decoder Msg
decodeMouseEvent =
    JD.map Zoom
        (JD.succeed MouseWheelEvent
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
            |: mouseAttribute "deltaX"
        )


mouseAttribute : String -> JD.Decoder Float
mouseAttribute k =
    JD.at [ k ] JD.string |> JD.andThen readFloat


readFloat : String -> JD.Decoder Float
readFloat n =
    JD.succeed (withDefault 0 (S.toFloat n))
```

to:

```
decodeMouseEvent : JD.Decoder Msg
decodeMouseEvent =
    JD.map Zoom
        (JD.succeed MouseWheelEvent
            |: JD.field "deltaX" JD.float
            |: JD.field "deltaY" JD.float
            |: JD.field "clientX" JD.float
            |: JD.field "clientY" JD.float
        )
```